# how to setup (x) to (x) + 1 ÷ 5 + 3 calculation in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, equations

I have been given an equation and also the correct calculation. However trying to set it up in excel is not matching the desired result. I am unable to figure out if i do not understand the equation, or if i am not using the correct forumla within microsoft excel.

Please see below for my equation/calculation data and my spreadsheet formula. Any information on what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Equation reads: "x to x+1 gives value(x/5)+3 result. (eg, from number 94 to 95 value(94/5)+3=21 result)" also the correct calculation data reads "value 1 to 99 gives a total of 1225"

Spreadsheet formula: A2 is value. =ROUND(A2/5+3,0) but total sum reads 1287

also for layout see

[image]

**** Some extra information for those asking themself the question "WHY??". I am a superuser in training, and training task's like these are given to myself on a weekly basis. It is expected that if i do not natively know the solution or cannot figure it out via trial and error, then i am to research or seek help. Stack exchange was suggested by my superior. ****

Comment: Can you explain what "x to x+1" means?  How does that relate to the calculation?  It might be helpful if you could post the actual complete problem statement.  It's also not clear what, exactly, you are supposed to do.

Comment: "x to x+1 gives value(x/5)+3 result. (eg, from number 94 to 95 value(94/5)+3=21 result)" also the correct calculation data reads "value 1 to 99 gives a total of 1225" is the complete problem i have been given.

Again, i am not sure if i am misunderstanding the equation, but i personally read it as "when moving between x value and x value" so you only get a result between value 94 and 95 which is 94/5+3=21. Unless i am misunderstanding i believe that is what the equation is. but then again my formula does not add up? so i can only give the information that i myself have been given.

Comment: Your comment is the same information as the question.  It is an unusual and non-standard way to express a problem and it makes no sense without some context to understand it (the wording has no generally understood meaning in math or Excel).  Can you provide the exact and complete wording of the problem as it was given to you?

Comment: My apologies. This is exactly as written:

"Going from floor x to x+1 gives floor(x/5)+3 points. (eg. From floor 94 to 95 is floor(94/5)+3=21 points gained). Going from floor 1 to 99 gives a total of 1225 points."

Comment: YOU CAN TRY THIS =ROUNDDOWN(x+1/5+3,)

Comment: If it helps anyone, the exact same problem and solution are mentioned here: [link]http://ragnarok.wikia.com/wiki/Stats_%28RO%29

Comment: Interesting! Good find. Good to know an example of where my superiors get their training data from. The only downside is it does not make any more sense to me than before? Am i misunderstanding the equation or are my excel formulas wrong?

Oh a side note, i wonder if thats allowed? This training data is printed on DHL paper in a training layout! I might ask my boss!

Comment: @Rolo, you're good.  So this is an imaginary construct from the netherworld.  FLOOR is the Excel round-down function.  Apparently, in the netherworld, you progress one numerical increment at a time and for each increment, you accumulate "points" equivalent to FLOOR(x/5)+3, or divide the lower number by 5, round down to the whole number and add 3.  If you have progressed from "1" to "99", there would be 98 increments and the sum of the points from those increment should be 1225.  This is probably the worst worded problem I have ever seen.  My condolences for having to learn from your superiors.

Comment: From your example, you want "integer division", which discards remainders. I can't access Excel right now, but `ROUNDDOWN` sounds good to me.

Comment: Fixer1234. To be perfectly honest, I was completely stumped when I was handing this training matrix. I'm used to being given statistics or percentage problems and most of the training is aimed at excel learning with problem solving thrown in. But this one was way different to what I am used to and Is the reason I posted here. I'm glad it's not only Me that thinks this problem is odd. I will be passing on this information to my boss and asking other training super users to look at this module and also express their confusion.

Comment: Apparently, it's confusing only because you are not a gamer familiar with this game.  It used to be that you got ahead by playing golf with the bosses.  Now you need to be a gamer nerd.

Comment: The sad part is I am suppose to be furthering my career as a super user, i didn't realize i was being trained as a gamer?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all of the feedback and help. (I will be passing some of this information onto my boss) The solution lies in both misunderstanding the equation and my formula.

First of all (aside from the fact that the information i was given was very off putting) the equation should read "x -1 /5 +3" and then my formula needed brackets to make sure this calculation was happening in the correct order.

I have now solved this using the following formula: "=ROUNDDOWN((x-1)/5+3,0)"
[image: This is what it looks like]